# Copy a word in macro without using a register

Tags: macro

I want to create a macro that will take a word `logThis`, which is selected in visual mode, and turn it into this:

```
console.log 'printing logThis'
console.log JSON.stringify(logThis, undefined, 2)
```

I realize that I can get my macro to remember `logThis` by copying it with `yw` or some other register, but I might be using that register for something else, and I don't want the macro to wipe out that register's contents.

Is it possible to use `logThis` twice inside this macro without taking up a register?

Comment: I do something similar [with a mapping](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/eeb3fdf0f7040d29b02f9de62d0398355f49fc8c/.vim/ftplugin/javascript.vim#L18-22).  My version clobbers the default register, but we could clobber a different register, e.g. `l` by using `"ly` instead of `y` and `<C-R>l` instead of `<C-R>"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could include this command at the beginning of your macro to save the current value of register `a`:

```
let old_a = getreg(a)
```

yank the highlighted word to register `a`:

```
"ay
```

and reset register `a` once you are done:

```
call setreg("a", old_a)
```

Macros are great but there's always a point where they become too complex to maintain. You should probably consider a proper function instead:

```
function! MyFunction()
    let old_a = getreg("a")
    normal! gv"ay
    let my_word = getreg("a")
    call setreg("a", old_a)
    " use my_word here
endfunction

xnoremap <key> :call MyFunction()<CR>
```

Comment: Here we go again: don't use assignments to save and restore registers, you'll lose all information about the registers' types.  Use `getreg()`, `getregtype()`, and `setreg()` instead.

Comment: I've never run into a circumstance where the mode/type of a register mattered but for those interested see `:help setreg()` for info on how to use these functions and what 'mode' means (getreg/setreg pairs are insufficient).

Answer (score 6):

Why a macro? You could very well use a snippet instead. For example (with [NeoSnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim)):

Create a new global snippet with `:NeoSnippetEdit _` (replace `_` with a filetype if you want a dedicated snippet) and add this content:

```
snippet log
    console.log 'printing ${1:TARGET}'
    console.log JSON.stringify($1, ${2:undefined}, 2)${0}
```

Save and exit the file.

#### Usage:

Visually select your text, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or the key you have configured to trigger a snippet) and you will be asked for the snippet name to be inserted: write 'log', <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the above code will be inserted, with cursor on `1`st position and the `TARGET` replaced by your selected text, in both positions. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to accept the text and jump to the second marker (`undefined`) - you can edit it, or not, and if you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, the cursor will be placed at the end of the construct ( position `0`).

Now, because this is a snippet, you can also use it ... before you have the text to be logged: you write `log` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the snippet will be expanded: write `logThis` (or whatever text you want to log), hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, accept `undefined` or change it, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and ... that's it.

If you prefer using `UltiSnips` instead, see [this link](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/ultisnips-visual-placeholder/).